# No external mic option

Tags: sound

I upgrated from ubuntu 18.04 to the latest lts version,when i connect my headphon either via bluetooth or Jack cable the sound is working fine but it uses only the laptops mic. When i checked in pulseaudio it says that the mic is unplugged and in the sound setting the is only internal mic as an option nothing else.

Comment: What do you consider latest version? 20.04 or 20.10?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.2 is what i have.